# How to make a Python string out of non-ascii "bytes"

Tags: python, string, byte

I need to create a Python string consisting of non-ascii bytes to be used as a command buffer in a C module.
I can do that if I write the string by hand:

```
mybuffer = "\x00\x00\x10"
```

But I cannot figure out how to create the string on the fly if I have a set of integers which will become the bytes in the string. Concatenating an integer with a string is a TypeError.

So if I have a list of integers lets say:

```
myintegers = [1, 2, 3, 10]
```

How can I convert that into a string `"\x01\x02\x03\x0A"`

I am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`u''.join(map(unichr, myintegers))` will do what you want nicely.

Comment: Leave off the leading `u` and use `chr` instead of `unichr` if you won't go above 256.

Comment: Better yet, use `b''` so that 2to3 will recognize it as `bytes` instead of `str`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Python 2.X

```
''.join(chr(i) for i in myintegers)
```

#### Python 3.X

```
bytes(myintegers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]: import struct

In [29]: struct.pack('{0}B'.format(len(myintegers)),*myintegers)
Out[29]: '\x01\x02\x03\n'
```

Note that

```
In [47]: '\x01\x02\x03\n'=="\x01\x02\x03\x0A"
Out[47]: True
```